# Retrieve user data from LinkedIn r_basicprofile

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I have successfully integrated LinkedIn sign in with Python. According to our requirement its need to get the fields lot more than `r_liteProfile`. So I have access the `r_basicProfile` and request to retrieve the data.

This is the code:

```
response_fullFields = requests.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,first-name,last-name)", headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken })
```

But it only returns profile "id". Even when I access it using:

```
response_fullFields = requests.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,headline,location,industry)", headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken })
```

The result is same.

In my developer app I have set permissions:

```
r_emailaddress
3-legged member permission

r_liteprofile
3-legged member permission

w_member_social
3-legged member permission
```

I am struggling about what is the issue with this. So can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is to retrieve profile data.

```
    import requests
    import json
    rty = " https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me"
    details = requests.get(rty, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken })
    response = json.loads(details.content.decode("utf-8"))
    first_name = response["localizedFirstName"]
    last_name = response["localizedLastName"]
    profile_picture = response["profilePicture"]["displayImage"]
```

Another more simplified way

I just went through the data and extracted the fields.

```
    rty = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))"
    details = requests.get(rty, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken })
    response = json.loads(details.content.decode("utf-8"))
    first_name = response["firstName"]["localized"]["en_US"]
    last_name = response["lastName"]["localized"]["en_US"]
    profile_url = response["profilePicture"]["displayImage~"]["elements"][0]["identifiers"][0]["identifier"]
```

Also did some digging to get thhe email address. Here's a way

```
    email_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))"
    email_details = requests.get(email_url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken })
    email_response = json.loads(email_details.content.decode("utf-8"))
    email_address = email_response["elements"][0]["handle~"]["emailAddress"]
```

Hope this helps. Cheers